# Vendoring a local dependency in order to build without access to that dependency

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, vendor

### Rust & cargo versions

```sh
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04)
$ cargo version
cargo 1.60.0 (d1fd9fe 2022-03-01)
```

### Context

I have:

- a library crate `greet` defined somewhere on my disk (`/path/to/crate/greet`)
- a binary crate `hello`, using this `greet` library crate, and defined somewhere else (`/an/other/path/to/crate/hello`)

#### Library crate `greet`

My library crate (`greet`) exports one function; `/path/to/crate/greet/src/lib.rs` looks like:

```rust
pub fn say_hello() {
    println!("Hello!");
}
```

#### Binary crate `hello`

My binary crate (`hello`) uses the `greet` library crate; `/an/other/path/to/crate/hello/Cargo.toml` looks like:

```
[package]
name = "hello"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
greet = { path = "/path/to/crate/greet" }
```

And `hello/src/main.rs` looks like:

```rust
fn main() {
    greet::say_hello();
}
```

All works perfectly, `cargo run` from `hello` folder prints `Hello!`.

### Question

My use case is to build the binary crate `hello` in a Docker container, without having access to/mounting the `/path/to/crate/greet` volume:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /an/other/path/to/crate/hello:/app -w /app \
    rust:1.60.0-slim cargo build
```

If I run the previous command, I obviously got an error:

```
error: failed to get `greet` as a dependency of package `hello v0.1.0 (/app)`

Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `greet`

Caused by:
  Unable to update /path/to/crate/greet

Caused by:
  failed to read `/path/to/crate/greet/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

I suppose that my question relates to vendoring my library crate. But when I run `cargo vendor` from my binary crate `hello`, I got a message:

> There is no dependency to vendor in this project.

How can I vendor this library crate **in `hello` folder**, so that I can capture the contents of `greet` crate at one time, and so it looks like this:

```
.
└── hello
    ├── Cargo.toml
    ├── src
    │   └── main.rs
    └── vendor
         └── greet
              └── ...
```

And so I am able to build `hello` with `docker` **without** access to `/path/to/crate/greet`?

Comment: I guess you have tried using the `-s` option to add `greet` ?

Comment: You're right and unfortunately, it does not work neither. Running `cargo vendor -s /path/to/crate/greet/Cargo.toml` from the `hello` crate gives me the same message `There is no dependency to vendor in this project.`.